# osm_flutter_plugin is not working some internal error

Tags: flutter, openstreetmap

i am trying to implement osm_flutter_plugin but for some reason all of these internal errors that i do not understand this is my code

```
class MapView extends GetView<MapViewController> {
  final osmPluginController = osm_plugin.MapController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(children: [
        Center(
          child: OSMFlutter(
            controller: osmPluginController,
            onLocationChanged: (GeoPoint point) {
              print('lat: ${point.latitude}, lon: ${point.longitude}');
            },
            trackMyPosition: true,
            initZoom: 16,
            minZoomLevel: 6,
            maxZoomLevel: 19,
            stepZoom: 1.0,
            userLocationMarker: UserLocationMaker(
              personMarker: MarkerIcon(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.location_history_rounded,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  size: 48,
                ),
              ),
              directionArrowMarker: MarkerIcon(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.double_arrow,
                  size: 48,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            markerOption: MarkerOption(
                defaultMarker: MarkerIcon(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.person_pin_circle,
                color: Colors.blue,
                size: 56,
              ),
            )),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

it shows these errors when i try to restart the app
^
[image]